# XPath: return first met child which has specific attribute

Tags: xpath, return, parent-child, attr

Have following hierarchy:

```
Parent1
    --> child1(@name = 'abc')
    --> child2(@name = 'xyz')
    --> child3(@name = 'qqq')

Parent2
    --> child1
    --> child2(@name = 'yui')
```

**XPath** which returns following nodes needed:

`child1 from Parent1` 
and 
`child2 from Parent2`

the rule is following:
return **first occurred** child **only** which has specific attribute, in this case `@name`

**note:**
`first()` and `[1]` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following xpath:

```
/root/node()/node()[@name][position()=1]
```

With this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <parent1>
    <child1 name="abc"></child1>
    <child2 name="xyz"></child2>
    <child3 name="qqq"></child3>
  </parent1>
  <parent2>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2 name="yui"></child2>
  </parent2>
</root>
```

Returns:

```
Element='<child1 name="abc" />'
Element='<child2 name="yui" />'
```

Comment: thank you for hint, unfortunately for JCR XPath this function is not implemented yet, anyway that's work in other context